# how do I solve `ld cannot find -something`

Tags: codeblocks, ld, openframeworks

When I try running openFrameworks example audioOutputExample in CodeBlocks, I get the following errors:

in Debug:

> ld cannot find -openframeworksDebug

in Release:

> ld cannot find -openframeworks

How do I solve this?

---

***UPDATES***
Here is why I've tried up to now:

**make**

```
cd apps/examples/audioOutputExample/
make
```

> [...]
>
> compiling done
>
> to launch the application
>
> cd bin
>
> ./audioOutputExample

**ok**

```
cd bin
./audioOutputExample
```

> ./audioOutputExample: error while
>   loading shared libraries:
>   libfmodex.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

**Looking for openframeworksDebug**

```
sudo updatedb
[password]
locate openframeworksDebug
```

> [finds nothing]

**ldconfig**

```
ldconfig
```

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create
>   temporary cache file
>   /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied

```
sudo ldconfig
```

> [Enter password]
>
> [Finishes very quickly with no output whatsoever]

Comment: @Gregory Hoerner : yes, I get `ld config` : `/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied` then `sudo ldconfig` [enter password] `finishes with no output or errors`

Answer (score 1):

if you are on linux may this can help:
run this two scripts from /scripts/linux/ with root privileges:

```
./install_dependencies.sh
./install_codeblocks.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

first look for the location of the `libfmodex.so` library. It should be in the libs path in the same directory as the application you try to start. 
like this

```
someApp
libs/libfmodex.so
```

If this is not the case, copy it over there (should usually be done by make).

If still not ok use ldd.

```
ldd someApp
```

This will show you, where someApp looks for the missing library.
The following options are now available to you:

- adjust LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include a directory, where your lib(.so files) is located
- use ldconfig -l /path/to/lib/libfmodex.so